# AttributeError: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'is_staff'

Tags: python, django

server function that has the failing code:

```
def my_orders(request):
    if request.is_ajax() and request.method == "POST":
        username = request.POST.get("username")
        # if user is staff return all orders
        userObj = MyUser.objects.filter(username=username)
        if userObj.is_staff == True:        ## this line fails
            context = {
                "orders" : Order.objects.all(),
                "user" : userObj
            }
        else:
            orders = Order.objects.filter(username=username)
            context = {
                "orders" : orders,
                "user" : userObj
            }
        return render(request,"orders/my_orders.html", context)
    else:
        return HttpResponse("Orders can be seen only via signing in to POO")
```

whereas I already defined MyUser as following in models.py:

```
class MyUser(AbstractBaseUser):

    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=40, unique=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
```

so I added this custom MyUser because of is_staff, I thought that would solve the error I am getting. but still I am getting the same error, so what is the solution?

Comment: `filter` returns a *query set*, [potentially containing many records](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#methods-that-return-new-querysets). You want [`.get`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#methods-that-do-not-return-querysets).

Comment: thanks, I am a newbie to Django. it worked by the way.